# Outlook 2013 'Run a script' rule has disappeared

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2013, outlook-2016

I have some rules for work in outlook 2013 - however following my laptop crashing the other day, I can no longer run any rules, they simply do not work (I don't even get a debug notification). Upon checking my macros, I found that when I tried to click on any scripts I have and I keep getting the message 'This action is not available in the current mode'. 
The option to create a new script has disappeared from the rule list too.

So far I have tried:
-Using the outlook 2016 fix by running the registry fix DWORD 1 (There is nothing out there for 2013). I have restarted my Pc and it still has not changed a thing.
-System restore to a previous date. This has literally changed nothing.

I'm a little stuck. I have attached screenshots to further explain exactly what I am experiencing.

Thanks,

Rachael

**Some information has been whited out due to confidentiality.**

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Trust Centre Settings:

[image]

Comment: Hey, yes unfortunately I have tried it - it is the addon for an app i use called Nitro (it's a PDF converter).

Comment: (a) The reference to "current mode" might indicate some sort of "safe mode", or "compatibility mode" - does anything show in the title bar?  (b) Is it only rules which run macros that cause problems?  E.g. can you create (and run) a rule to simply move a message to another folder?

Comment: Hi, yes - it seems to be that I can create as many rules as i want - it is just running scripts that I am unable to do. There is no indication that I am running outlook any differently than I had done before. It is not in safe mode - and when i change the compatibility it does not open.

Comment: That certainly makes me think that macros have been disabled.  Check the Trust Settings (File / Options / Trust Center / Trust Center Settings / Macro Settings) and see whether it is set to "Disable all macros without notification" or something.

Comment: Hi - I have updated my main post with trust centre settings. I think it looks like it should? Can you think of anything else? Thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: Delete all your Error'ed rules-

Comment: ^^ or at least see whether you can run a completely new rule using a new macro, and whether you can run a new rule using an old macro.

Comment: i just posted a short code for you to try

Comment: one thing has crossed my mind ... were you working on some code when you had the crash? /// i wonder if it is possible that there is some code running when email arrives, and that code is cancelling the "new mail" event in the system (intercepting the event)

Comment: YowE3K - I am unable to create or edit rules with macros in them. However I will try again once I delete my current errored macros.

Comment: jsotola - I will have a go, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue after a Windows Update. Here's what fixed it for me:

Save everything below the line as a .reg file and then double-click it to run and launch (or manually add it your registry via `regedit`).

You should probably backup your registry first to be safe and please note that this was the correct location for my Office 2013 installation (yours may be different).

```
Office 2013 = 15.0
Office 2016 = 16.0
```

Save using Notepad as a .reg file to double-click and upload to your system's registry (Office 2013). I hope this helps someone else! -Mike

---

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Security]
> "EnableUnsafeClientMailRules"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick and dirty test to check whether vba code runs at all when email arrives

put it into "ThisOutLookSession" which is under  "Microsoft Office Outlook Objects"

then send yourself an email ... if vba runs then you should see a popup

it will not solve your problem, but it will provide more info to help narrow down the cause

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    MsgBox "you have mail"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create ***`.reg file`*** Open Notepad and save-as ***`.reg`***

*Outlook 2010*

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security]
"EnableUnsafeClientMailRules"=dword:00000001
```

---

> *For **`Outlook 2013`** use `\Office\15.0\` and **`Outlook 2016`** `\Office\16.0\`*