# Executing VBA Script without access to the "Run a Script" rule in Outlook 2016

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I have Outlook 2016 on my computer at work and the "Run a Script" rule has been disabled.  I'm aware of the changes that should be made in the `regedit` file, but I need admin access to do so.  My IT team is located across the country from me, so I've been waiting for two weeks for them to change this and I'm convinced that it's never going to happen.

So, I'm wondering if there's a workaround or a way to code the same process?

When I receive an e-mail with certain words in the subject line, I would like the rule/script to save the file attachment (inside the e-mail) into a folder on my computer.

I'm no VBA expert at all (especially with Outlook), so I'm probably far away from being on the right path, but I've given it a shot:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim oRule as Outlook.Rule
    Dim oRuleAction as Outlook.RuleAction
    Dim oRuleCondition as Outlook.RuleCondition

    Set oRule = colRules.Create("Transfer Attachment", olRuleSubject)
    Set oRuleCondition = oRule.Conditions.Subject("FINAL-CPW GRP SALES")
    Set oRuleAction = SaveAtlasReport
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAtlasReport()
    Dim att as Attachment
    Dim FileName as string

    FileName = "C:\Users\WCD1867\Documents\AttachTest\PositivePOS.xlsx"
    att.SaveAsFile FileName

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the rule suppose to do?

Comment: Oops!  Can't believe I left that out.  Sorry!  I edited the question...  When I receive an e-mail with certain words in the subject line, I would like the rule/script to save the file attachment (inside the e-mail) into a folder on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Replace your "Outlook Rule / Run a Script" with **[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook)** and **[Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** to  **[Filter Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866013.aspx)** by subject line.*

*Example*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Filter As String

    Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                       Chr(34) & " Like '%FINAL-CPW GRP SALES%' AND " & _
                       Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & _
                       Chr(34) & "=1"

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)

End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailitem Then
        Dim AtmtName As String
        Dim FilePath As String
            FilePath = "C:\Temp\"
        
        Dim Atmt As Attachment
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            AtmtName = FilePath & Atmt.FileName
            Debug.Print AtmtName ' Print on Immediate Window
            Atmt.SaveAsFile AtmtName
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

> *<sub>**[Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)** Occurs when one or more items are added to the specified collection. **This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once**. This event is not available in Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript).</sub>*

---

> <sub>***[Items.Restrict method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook)** is an alternative to using the Find method or FindNext method to iterate over specific items within a collection. The Find or FindNext methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The Restrict method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.*</sub>

---

> <sub>**[Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646.aspx#String%20Comparisons%20Using%20DASL%20Syntax)** that DASL filters support includes equivalence, prefix, phrase, and substring matching. Note that when you filter on the Subject property, prefixes such as "RE: " and "FW: " are ignored.</sub>

---

*For those who wanna edit reg see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48778903/4539709*

---

Comment: You're a friggin' genius, 0m3r!  Thank you so much!  This works perfectly and I was able to set my other weekly reports up as well.  Now,  my database (that uses these linked Excel spreadsheets) updates automatically each week.  I really appreciate the help and good information!

Answer (score -1):

By definition you can't run a script when running scripts are disabled. If you could then hackers around the globe would rejoice and people would have to stop using Outlook for corporate mail.

There is no built-in function to do what you want.

It can be done with plugins, like Kutools:
https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-outlook.html

Your IT dept may not want to let you do this for security reasons. You should not seek to circumvent rules that you don't understand the implications of.

Comment: Hi HackSlash - I do understand and have considered the implications of what I'm trying to do.  I've even discussed my intentions with my VP.  It's just a matter of corporate ineffectiveness while trying to get things changed... All scripts aren't disabled - just the "Run a Script" action located in the Rule Wizard.Anyways, I didn't think that there would be a built-in function, but surely there has to be an alternative way to do this..? (How did KuTools do it?)

Comment: KuTools is running scripts. Add-ons are allowed to do this. You might not be able to install the add-on because of this.

Comment: NOTE: If you could, you could compile your own add-on with your own code and just use that.