# Error 424 Object Required when attempting to process a mailitem object

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

An Outlook rule executes code every time an e-mail from a certain sender is received. It would automatically extract the PDF attachment from e-mails and put them into a specified folder.

We've been using it for a good 9 months.

From around 10/22 it crashes on the line `For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments` with **`Error 424 Object Required.`** in the DAKSave portion.

I have tried changing the folder to a local folder, same error. This error also occurs on different computers when I try using the code (including a computer which WAS able to use that specific code previously).

I have enabled EnableUnsafeClientMailRules in regedit.

Why isn't it working? Why was it working until now?

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String

    sSaveFolder = "S:\Fax\FAX AUTODUMP\"

    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next

End Sub

Sub DAKSave()
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String

    sSaveFolder = "S:\Fax\FAX AUTODUMP\"

    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm open to suggestions that would accomplish the same automated task.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily changing the destination folder to somewhere locally? Also, can you putting a breakpoint in and stepping through the code to see which line the error occurs on? (I haven't tried this in Outlook before)

Comment: On which line has the error?

Comment: See if this helps, you may have to update the filter - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49184312/4539709

Comment: The error is on:
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
In the DAKSave portion

I have also tried to change the folder to a local folder, same error.  This error also occurs on different computers when I try using the code (including a computer which WAS able to use that specific code previously).

Comment: @0m3r- I have already enabled EnableUnsafeClientMailRules in regedit so that workaround shouldn't be necessary I assume

Sorry for delay in response, I'm at work and I'm swamped.

Comment: If there is an error in DAKSave there is no need for SaveAttachmentsToDisk in the question. The object MItem is required in DAKSave because it is nothing. One way to get something to act upon is to first open a mailtem manually then`Set MItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem` or select a mailitem then `Set MItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

*Your missing mail Item object, so try to work with [ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selection.item)*

```
Option Explicit
Sub DAKSave()
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    sSaveFolder = "S:\Fax\FAX AUTODUMP\"

    Dim MItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set MItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.attachment
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`MItem` is not passed as a parameter to the `DAKSave` sub. `MItem` is undefined in `DAKSave`. It is only available in the `SaveAttachmentsToDisk` sub.