# vba saves outlook attachments on pc without script rule

Tags: vba

I need a vba (executed in outlook, or not) that saves email attachments on my desktop (c:/), without using the script function of the outlook rules (there is no more how to enable in windows10 since last update of 2018, according to windows release).

When there was the function to execute script, I used:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String

    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\DT168\Documents\outlook-attachments\"

    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

Have other code vba?

Comment: I've had good success scraping once in awhile, then moving the files to a "Has been scraped" folder. Would something like that work for you?

Comment: @Selkie I can test, can you show me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing VBA Script without access to the "Run a Script" rule in Outlook 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181566/executing-vba-script-without-access-to-the-run-a-script-rule-in-outlook-2016)