# How to auto forward, an email with attachments from sender, to more than one email address?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want when a specific email is delivered to my inbox to autoforward this email to multiple email addresses with the attachment and body but changing the subject.

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objForward As Outlook.MailItem
 
If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
    Set objMail = Item
 
    'If it is a specific new email
    If (objMail.SenderEmailAddress = "someone@outlook.com") And _
      (objMail.Importance = olImportanceHigh) And _
      (objMail.Attachments.Count > 0) Then
 
        Set objForward = objMail.Forward
        'Customize the forward subject, body and recipients
        With objForward
            .Subject = "Custom Subject"
            .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Type body here. </BODY></HTML>" & _
              objForward.HTMLBody
            .Recipients.Add ("someone@gmail.com")
            .Recipients.ResolveAll
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh
            .Send
        End With
    End If
End If
End Sub

Sub myAutoFW()

End Sub
```

I stand on the email in the inbox and run the macro but nothing happened.

Comment: Why not simply create a rule and forward the email to specific people?

Comment: What's your question though?

Comment: @QuickSilver you mean that create a rule and use this macro to forward mails?

Comment: @Tim Williams Simply when some one send mail to me I want to forward this mail with the same attachment without download automatically by macro

Comment: Is there a problem with your posted code?  If not *what is your specific problem* ?  How are you using your posted code?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Haroon What i mean is in outlook there is a create rule option and you can customize it to move all your incoming email in inbox to another folder of your chosing. Similarly you can forward the email upon received to different people.

Comment: @Tim Williams my problem with my code I want to add the email which I received from I have just added the email I want to send to

Comment: @QuickSilver yes I actually did the rule but I can't have the validation to manage changing subject and body it's just forward message with the same email data I just want to send the same attachment but with change the subject and body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. When you receive a new mail and is forwarded, it is expected that the forwarded mail generally goes at least to a new user and hence all the content remain as is (i.e. attachments aren't removed).

```
Sub ForwardEmail(item As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oMail As MailItem    

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  If oMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
   If item.Class = olMail Then
     Set oMail = item.Forward
     With oMail
        .Subject = .Subject 'Can change the subject here
        .HTMLBody = "Please find attached." & vbCrLf & .HTMLBody
        .Recipients.Add "someone@gmail.com" 'email address here
        .Save
        .Send
     End With
  End If
 End If
 ErrorHandler:
  Set oMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer but I want to know where's exactly can I put the sender email that's will be forwarded please just check my edit

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Haroon Do not change the your question or edit it as whoever will read it laster will not make much sense. Regarding the emais you just need to put the emai addresses were it says email... so instead of `someone@gmail.com` put your email adresses that you want to send.

Comment: look I have a sender mail let's call it as "sender" which I need to forward his mail with the same attachment but with changing the Subject and Body this point is ok
now I want forward the sender mail as I said to more than person email ok? lets say the persons emails is "receiver" ok that's good
now I under stand that I can put the sender email here
     oMail.Recipients.Add "someone@gmail.com" 'email address here

so now where can I put the receiver mails that's I will forward from the sender

    oMail.Recipients.Add "someone@gmail.com" 'email address here

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Haroon Please go to outlook and do a forward on a email and observe the behaviour of it....Forwarding an email to another person will automatically remove the sender's email...everything will be blank in fields `To` & `CC` & `BCC` the only field remaining intact will be the subject and the attachement. So when you forward the email under the `oMail.Recipients.Add "someone@gmail.com"` that will be the new person that is receiving the email.

Comment: I don't need to do forward manually I just when someone send an email I want to forward it to more than email automatically I don't want to press forward some thing like automate forward when email received 
I have just open my outlook and stand on the email which was in the inbox and run the macro but there's nothing happened

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Haroon What i said at the begining of my last comment was for you to notice the natual way that outlook behaves when you press forward to an email nothing more. In respect to automate the task you will need to create a rule and assisn the macro to it so this will be triggered upon receive.

Comment: yes! you reached the point I need exactly now I can keep the attach and just change the subject and body with macro and auto forward with rule so finally how can I connect between the macro and the rule I created just the senario like this when the email received by me just make a new mail and keep the same attachment but change the body and subject with macro then auto forward with the rule I created so now how to connect between macro oand rule

Comment: It's possible and easier to do this with programming language like python?

Comment: I will accept your answer but please help me to solve this

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Haroon I'm not too sure about Python never did any code there so i cannot advise. Regarding to your VBA what you need to do is actually the opposite...What you need to do formatting wise do it in the macro you can change the subject and whoever needs to receive it. Then rule wise you can create the rule that when a specific email comes in inbox to trigger the macro on that email. Use this link and have a read on how to do that https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/

Comment: thanks alot for your help so now I changed my VBA code. just check my edit as I created a rule that auto forward message but it forwards with the same data and subject this macro should change the subject but now I still don't know how to trgger my macro on rule I have created

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Haroon Please do not change the original question/code as this will confuse other users that might be looking at this post. Regarding your issue i will need to have a look at this on pc when i get home to provide more details on the matter.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I am waiting your reply @QuickSilver

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Haroon After researching online i found that you need to modify the registry in order to have the rule to run a script...tried it and failed so not too sure why though. I think it would be best to ask another question on the last bit of your problem. I found this article that might be useful to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181566/executing-vba-script-without-access-to-the-run-a-script-rule-in-outlook-2016