Auto download attachment from Outlook to local folder via VBA
Below code is to save email attachment to a local folder. The trigger is by outlook rules. However, occasionally there will be “An unexpected error has occurred.” from Rules in Error and the code will not work as expected.
The file name is standardised and will be sent daily as csv only. File name eg: Report0311.csv
Code that I’ve tried:
Sub SaveAttachmentsToFolder(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = “C:\Users\Me\Home\SaveFolder\”
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
obiAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & “\” & objAtt.DisplayName
Next
End Sub


Look closely at your double quotes.... one of them is a "curly/fancy quote" - change it to a normal double quote like the rest and see if that helps.

Thanks for helping out. It’s a honest mistake of typo, doubt that is the reason why it failed infrequently.

Does objAtt.DisplayName have any illegal characters in it when you get the error? There are some characters that cannot be used in a filename.

The file name is standardised. Eg: Report0311.csv

Is Report0311.csv what it actually is when you get the error? Or is that what you think it's supposed to always be? In order to see the actual value, you need to click debug when you get the error and check your variables while it is paused.

If the email contains more than one attachment, and one of them is just an embedded image in the email (like from an email signature), how does your code handle that? How does it know not to try and save that too?

It will always be only one attachment and the attachment file is csv format.

So when you get the error, and click Debug to check your variables, what are they? I am not asking what they SHOULD be... it's important to see what they actually are when it errors to know what the problem is. Did you take the recommendation from the answer below to check the type? That's important.

The usual solution is to accept Microsoft's default disabling of "Run a script". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181566/executing-vba-script-without-access-to-the-run-a-script-rule-in-outlook-2016

Your code is not checking the attachment type - check if you have a regular by-value attachment (objAtt.Type = olAttachByValue). If you get an embedded message attachment, you can end up with characters illegal in a filename (e.g., ":").
It is a good idea to sanitize the attachment name (use FileName, not DisplayName property) regardless.

Thanks for the response. Attachment file type will always be csv file with standardise name.

Since your code fires on each and every message received, how can you guarantee what the attachment will be every time?

I have set up a rule in Outlook to only save attachment from specific subject. The file type for this specific subject will always be csv file.
